# We have a multi tenant mvc application, can we have one container inside the storage for each tenant in a secure way?

Tags: c#, azure, model-view-controller, webapi

We have a storage account, but I cannot create every time a storage account for the new tenant it is limited by number and managing will be a headache , is it possible to maintain one container for each tenant in a secure way with exposing my key or encrypting the key in both ends.

Comment: And in what way the question is related to c#, model-view-controller, webapi? Please use relevant tags.

Comment: You can use Managed Identities to give container-level access (if you deploy a separate app for each tenant).

Comment: Generally , your customers will access your multi tenant app via access token or id token. For each of them will contain a "tid" claim whose value is your customers' tenant ID , that ID is a GUID , you can use it to specify each container name that you will assign to your customers and your application should do all actions for your customers instead of share keys to your customers. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

1.Go to your MVC application on portal > Identity> Turn On System assigned.

2.Go to your storage > Add container with `Container` Access level.

3.Go to your storage > Access Control (IAM) > Add role assignment > Add [`Storage Blob Data Reader`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad#assign-rbac-roles-for-access-rights) role with your MVC registered application in Azure AD.

4.Then get access token to that MVC application, so you can access in a security way.